# Confusion about HashMap#treeifyBin

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm reading source code about `HashMap#treeifyBin` function.

It's confused why does it check

```
if ((tab[index] = hd) != null)
```

since it already checked it before

```
(e = tab[index = (n - 1) & hash]) != null
```

Code:

```
final void treeifyBin(Node<K,V>[] tab, int hash) {
    int n, index; Node<K,V> e;
    if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) < MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY)
        resize();
    else if ((e = tab[index = (n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        TreeNode<K,V> hd = null, tl = null;
        do {
            TreeNode<K,V> p = replacementTreeNode(e, null);
            if (tl == null)
                hd = p;
            else {
                p.prev = tl;
                tl.next = p;
            }
            tl = p;
        } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        if ((tab[index] = hd) != null)  // why do we need this line?
            hd.treeify(tab);
    }
}
```

Comment: These expressions are not the same - the first one checks that `tab[index ...]` is not null and the second one checks that `hd` is not null (and assigns `hd` to `tab[index]` as a side effect)

Comment: I think `hd` can not be null if `tab[index ...]` is not null...

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that. If `replacementTreeNode(e, null)` returns null, and e.next is null, then hd equals null in the second `if` statement.